# type does not match with optional parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have one question about the type in typescript. I am working on some project that required to included some package that I found the some props is optional type from package. however, in my code, it is as required so I have the error

```
Type 'TypePackageVariable' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'TypePackageVariable'
```

example code

```
interface TypePackageVariable {
  paraA: string;
  paraB?: string;
}
const packageVaribale:TypePackageVariable = {paraA: 'paraA', paraB:'paraB'}
const localVariable: Record<string, string> = packageVaribale
console.log(localVariable)
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `Record<string, string>`?

Comment: for my localVariable, i only know it should be Record type but no specific key required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Typescript is unable to see `TypePackageVariable` as a subset of `Record<string, string>`.

There is a really nice article explaining index signatures in Typescript - https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures

There are two ways I can think of to make it explicit and fix your issue -

1. Cast the value as an explicit subset of Record<string, string>

```
const localVariable: Record<string, string> = packageVariable as Record<'paraA' | 'paraB', string>;
```

2. Extend Record<string, string> while declaring the type

```
interface TypePackageVariable extends Record<string, string> {
  paraA: string;
  paraB?: string;
}
```